# Linearly independent set in the function field

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, field-theory

It is well known that the set $\{\frac{1}{x-a}: a \in \mathbb N\}$ is a linearly independent set in $\mathbb C(x)$ over $\mathbb C$. Similarly one can prove that the set $\{\frac{1}{1-x^a}: a \in \mathbb N\}$ is linearly independent in $\mathbb C(x)$. Let $f_{a,b}(x)=\frac{(1-x^{a+t})(1-x^{b+t})}{(1-x^a)(1-x^b)}$ where $a, b \in \mathbb N$ and $t$ is a fixed positive integer. Then, is the set $\{f_{a,b}(x): a \leq b \in \mathbb N\}$ linearly independent in $\mathbb C(x)$ as a vector space over $\mathbb C$ ?

Comment: I presume you mean $\Bbb C(x)$ as a vector space over $\Bbb C$? Since $\Bbb C(x)$ is itself a field, It is also a vector space over itself. Though in that case, no set with more than one element would be linearly independent. Also, do you mean linearly independent in the Hamel or Schoeder sense (finite or infinite sums)?

Comment: Yes, as a vector space over $\mathbb C$ and only finite sums are allowed.